# Construct regex pattern to identify a sub set of words

Tags: python, regex

I want to identify sub-sets of words using a regex pattern using the `values()` of the following dictionary.

```
creategarbageterms = {'tim_tam' : ['tim_tam','yummy_tim_tam', 'berry_tim_tam'],
                      'pudding': ['pudding', 'chocolate_pudding', 'biscuits', 'tiramusu'],
                      'ice_cream': ['ice_cream', 'vanilla_ice_cream']}
```

i.e., given the following strings;

```
**Term  ->    Output**
wow_yummy_tim_tam -> yes
melted_tim_tam ->yes
berry_tim_tam -> Yes
cherry_berry_tim_tam -> yes
wow_tam -> No
wow_m -> No
wow_ti -> No
Wow_tim_t -> No
```

My current code/pattern is as follows.

```
creategarbageterms = {'tim_tam' : ['tim_tam','yummy_tim_tam', 'berry_tim_tam'],
                      'pudding': ['pudding', 'chocolate_pudding', 'biscuits', 'tiramusu'],
                      'ice_cream': ['ice_cream', 'vanilla_ice_cream']}

pattern = re.compile(r'|'.join([r'(\s|\b){}\b'.format(x) for x in creategarbageterms.values()]))
if re.findall(pattern, "wow_m".replace("_", " ")):
    print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

However, in my current code the above mentioned `No` terms also gets accepted. Please let me know where I am making it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you need regular expressions to check for existence in the string. Instead, use `in` and `re` to split the string:

```
import re
creategarbageterms = {'tim_tam' : ['tim_tam','yummy_tim_tam', 'berry_tim_tam'],
                  'pudding': ['pudding', 'chocolate_pudding', 'biscuits', 'tiramusu'],
                  'ice_cream': ['ice_cream', 'vanilla_ice_cream']}

s =  ['wow_yummy_tim_tam', 'melted_tim_tam, berry_tim_tam', 'cherry_berry_tim_tam', 'wow_tam', 'wow_m', 'wow_ti', 'Wow_tim_t']
for c in s:
   truthy = any(any(i in c for i in b) for a, b in creategarbageterms.items())
   if truthy:
       print("Yes")
   else:
       print("no")
```

Output:

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
no
no
no
no
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I get an error saying `AssertionError`. Suppose, if I am having a list as follows `['wow_yummy_tim_tam', 'melted_tim_tam, berry_tim_tam', 'cherry_berry_tim_tam', 'wow_tam', 'wow_m', 'wow_ti', 'Wow_tim_t']`, how do I get the output as `['yes', 'yes', ... 'No', 'No']`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Since, this code is one line, it is kind of difficult for me to adjust it according to my need (because my python knowledge is very small). I honestly need some thing like this. `for item in s: if item <matches the in pattern>: print 'yes' else: print 'No'`. If you have time, could you please help me to decompose your current code to match my need :)

Comment: @JCena Glad to help. Please see my recent edit. I have broken the code up so it is more understandable.